# Java: Processor costs of converting from object to other data types

Tags: java, object

I'm working on a Java project where I handle a list of items, where each item has an id of type int and a value of type String. Then I have another type called ItemCollection which internally has the list and exposes methods to add, remove, get items, etc.

The application is a Financial Transaction Gateway, so we're very focused on performance, since the application will receive many transactions per second. My question is:

The cost of converting an String to another type, like Integer, Char, Date, etc. is the same of converting an Object containing an Integer, Char, Date, etc.?

To clarify, currently the value of the Item is handled in String format. The item has a method called getValue() that returns the item's value in String. But sometimes this value has to be converted to another type, for example int. So what I'm planning to do is change the root type of the value to Object and expose methods like getString(), getInt(), getDate(), getChar(), etc., where the value will be converted from Object to the specific data type. Of course, if the value can't be converted will return null/zero/etc.

In your experience, what would be the best approach? 
Is the same to convert from Object to int than String to int?

Comment: Have you written a prototype and tested the performance?

Comment: is memory usage(size) an issue or is it just the processor workload an issue?

Comment: I've been testing with the current approach, and I'm planning to write another with Objects but before I wanted to ask the community if it worth it.

Comment: Hi MaVRoSCy: memory ussage is not a problem, the only not function requirement we have is performance. The server where the application will run can have tons of memory, so it's not an issue.

Comment: `Of course, if the value can't be converted will return null/zero/etc.` Of course, those are some famous last words. Now you're going to check for null, zero (what if zero is valid? Could that be?) everywhere? Eek.

Comment: How will the Object store the value internally?

Comment: Well, this items container doesn't have logic itself. Other clases and methods takes the values they need from this container/collection and uses them, so each method has it's own business rules and know which values are posible. Anyway I got your point, maybe we can return always null...

Comment: Code-Guru, I didn't get your question. The Object will be a Java Object like in private Object value; public void setValue(Object o) { this.value = value; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need great performance than I cat suggest that it will be much better to use lower level language like `C++`. Maybe it is appropriate to use functional language like `Erlang`. If you want to work with Java then you should avoid taged types and use type system provided by the language. Taged classes are not much faster then actual java classes. Tagged classes are outdated programming style in Java. If you need to convert `String` to `Date`, for examle, then this operation will be much slower then cast performed by `instanceof` operator. Also in Java there is `Stop the world` GC pause, which can be deadly for real time applications.

Comment: Hi gkuzmin. Yes, we know GC can be a problem but this isn't a hard real time application either. Authorization can take some time, like 2 seconds so I guess the language itself is not a problem. But I agreee with you that C++ will have a better performance. Right now the bottleneck we have is with the database, since we need to read and write information to a database (Oracle), that's where we see the performance downgrade.

Comment: In fact if you work with DB then even reflection is not very expensive, so I can advise you to review your design and avoid tagged classes. They can produce much more harm in debugging and development then performance gain you can get from them (if there will be any gain at all). Also if you'll decide to implement your solution n `C++` you should keep in mind that `C++` does't have GC, but have fragmentation problems as well.

Comment: C++ is not an option, since we're linked to other libraries written in Java. Also we're not C++ programmers, so our productivity would be very low :(. BTW, what do you mean by tagged classes?

Comment: I call class tagged if it has some fields that serve only to determine its type. For example `class Figure{enum Type{Square,Triangle} public Type type}`. So to determine actual type of figure `type` field should be used. Joshua Bloch in `Efficient Java` *Item 20* recommend to prefer class hierarchies to tagged classes.

Comment: Generally it is a bad idea to store everything as string and determine content type by some tag.

Comment: Thanks for the book reference, I will take a look at it.

Comment: This is one of the best books about Java language which I've read. Joshua Bloch is one of the authors of `java.util.concurrent` package and collection framework, so his books consists of  large amount of good practical advises.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the level of detail you've provided, my suggestion is: **don't do it!**.

Find a way to model your data using Java's type system. Avoid type conversions (e.g. String to Integer), and avoid type casting (e.g. `(String)someObject`).

If you have a question about a specific operation (such as Integer's `toString` function), then I suggest consulting the documentation or the source code.

Comment: So, how JDBC for example works? You do this when working for example with OUT parameters. You need to use CallableStatement.getString() or CallableStatement.getInt(), etc. to get the value from those parameters. Is that kind of design bad for performance too? Maybe in that case we need to change or DB engine to MSSQL or MySQL or Postgres :)

Answer (score 0):

Who is producing these objects? Are they not coming in to you in some format such as JSON or XML that you can actually marshal the data to their real types?

For example, if you receive a JSON message of something like:

```
date: 2012-12-25
acct: 12345
amount: 123.50
```

then it's at that point where you should be putting them in to the correct types.

It seems like you want to dispatch messages or perform actions on items based on their type, and you're trying to convert them using the type. I hate not to answer your question, but how do you hope to accomplish this? Do you first try to see if the item is a Date? and then if not, try to see if it is a number? What takes precedence?

If you have an `Item` that needs processing.. and you can (as I said before, by marshalling the input data in to different types, not Strings) get a `StringItem` and a `DateItem`, for example, you can use the Visitor pattern.

Comment: We're not so lucky :(. Those values comes through a HTTP server, so they came like field=value&field=value&field=value&field=value&.. then we need to parse it and convert them to the desired value.

Comment: Okay, but unless a given field can have more than one type of value (in which case you should stab someone), you can still marshal them to types. There's no difference between `date=2012-12-25` and `date: 2012-12-25`. I'm kind of concerned that your Financial Transaction Gateway doesn't seem to show any signs of basic object-oriented programming knowledge (whether that's your fault or not)

Comment: I don't really get where do you get that conclusion from. This is just something like the 0.1% of the system, and we're trying to find the best way to store in memory the values coming from the terminal/POS. The format of the incoming messages can't be changed since are from thirds, and also there're more than one format and sources, each of them with their business logic. In the core you have all the OO concepts you may like, like inheritance, polymorfism, encapsulation, etc. Anyway, like someone said somewhere, if there're DB access in the middle, probably the time on this would be worthless

Comment: I still don't understand why you'd store an `Object` and then `getChar()`, `getString()`, `getDate()` etc. on it - even if there are different processing rules, they can't possibly expect to process the same value as a different thing in any predictable and sane manner. Is "123" a `String` or the `long` representation of the number of ticks in a `Date`? You obviously have to marshal String -> Something and I'm trying to get you to figure out if you can do that in a defined manner as opposed to having a bunch of things act on data just based upon what it *appears* to be, not what it **is**

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you mean by 'convert'. That is not a precise term of art in Java.

If you mean 'cast', then the answer is that casting is fast. Your `ItemCollection` class might have a method like this:

```
public int getInt(int index) {
    Object value = getObject(index);
    return (Integer)value;
}
```

The cast will add a few machine instructions.

If you mean something more like 'parse', then the answer is that parsing is hundreds or thousands of times slower than casting, but still fast compared to I/O. If you were parsing, your code might look like:

```
public int getInt(int index) {
    String value = getString(index);
    return Integer.parseInt(value);
}
```

So, what exactly do you mean by 'convert'?